# Android: Converting minutes and seconds to millisecond

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert time which I have in static string such as "07:02" into milliseconds. I am looking at documentation [TimeUnit](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) and trying to get my string to convert in milliseconds but first I have a string, so the converter function is not accepting string I guess and secondly I have both, minutes and seconds, so should I convert them one by one and then add them? Don't seem to be a nice approach?

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Comment: It seems a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have just checked the documentation for TimeUnit. You could do something like this:

```
String time = "07:02";

long min = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
long sec = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3));

long t = (min * 60L) + sec;

long result = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(t);
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following approach.

Split the time by the ':' and use the TimeUnit function.

```
    int convertTime(String timeString) {
        String[] time = timeString.split ( ":" );
        int pos = time.length - 1;
        long res = 0;
        if( pos >=0 ){
            res = res + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis( Long.parseLong( time[pos] ));
            pos --;
        }
        if( pos >=0 ){
            res = res + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( Long.parseLong( time[pos] ));
            pos --;
        }
        if( pos >=0 ){
            res = res + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis( Long.parseLong( time[pos] ));
            pos --;
        }
        return (int)res;
    }
```

The code is more complex, as it should work with

```
10
1:10
01:10
1:10:20
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm would be as follows:

1. convert to integer (int minutes, int seconds)
2. convert the minutes to seconds (i.e. minutes*60;)
3. add the converted minutes to the seconds (i.e. int total = (minutes*60) + seconds;)
4. convert to milliseconds (i.e.  milli = total/1000)